# Unable to catch FormData's extra parameter in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass extra parameter when upload file in MVC.

My js code:

```
 $("#btnSaveUser").click(function () {

        var data = new FormData();
        var files = $("#fupUploadImage").get(0).files;
        if (files.length > 0) {
            data.append("HelpSectionImages", files[0]);
            data.append("Path", "/Sage/Upload");
        }
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Sage/UploadFile",
            type:"POST",
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: data,
            isPostBack: false,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Success");

            },
            error: function (er) {
                alert("error");
            }

        });
    });
```

And in C# :

```
 public string   UploadFile()
 {


     if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
       {
          var path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["HelpSectionImages"];

           HttpPostedFile postedFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["HelpSectionImages"];

            var SavePath = Server.MapPath("~/Media/images/") + postedFile.FileName;
            postedFile.SaveAs(SavePath);
        }

       // Need help here to catch extra parameter

            return "Upload success";

 }
```

I success fully save file but unable to catch   second append `data.append("Path", "/Sage/Upload");` value in code.Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can use the request object

```
public string   UploadFile()
{
   if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
   {
      var path = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request["Path"];

      HttpPostedFile postedFile = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["HelpSectionImages"];

      var SavePath = Server.MapPath("~/Media/images/") + postedFile.FileName;
      postedFile.SaveAs(SavePath);
   }

   // Need help here to catch extra parameter

   return "Upload success";
}
```